# How to update sqlite_master using values obtained from a select statement?

Tags: sqlite

How do I update sqlite_master using values obtained from a select statement ?

For example, in the below I want to add a check statement to sqlite_master:

```
update sqlite_master set sql = substr (sql, 1, length (sql) - 1) || ', check (CountryName in ' || select name from country_table || ' )) )'
```

However, I get the below message

```
"SQLite3 Error 1 - near 'select": syntax error.
```

For comparison, if I do the following, my command works:

```
update sqlite_master set sql = substr (sql, 1, length(sql) - 1) || ', check (CountryName in ''Iceland'', ''Spain'' )) )'
```

Comment: And parentheses around the `select`-expression for fun and profit.

Comment: Indeed the parentheses around the select helped. However, an additional step was required, as follows: (select '''' || group_concat(name,''',''') || '''' from country_table)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your issue is due to:-

> **The expression of a CHECK constraint may not contain a subquery.**

- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#check_constraints

Furthermore you should perhaps pay heed to:-

> SQLite creates the schema table upon database creation and modifies its content as SQLite users submit DDL statements for execution. There is no need for users to modify it under normal circumstances, and **they bear the risk of database corruption if they do modify it**.

- https://sqlite.org/schematab.html#creation_and_modification_of_the_schema_table

The correct/safest way to modify sqlite_master would be to amend the table(s) accordingly and leave the modification of sqlite_master to SQLite.

Comment: It sees it is possible to add a subquery to the CHECK constraint (see my comment below the initial post above), though perhaps it is not very safe to change the schema in this manner, as you say.